# Browser aborting Ajax requests sporadically without returning any errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, symfony, xmlhttprequest

In my project ([PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP) with [Symfony](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symfony) 2) I do a lot of [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) requests in every page. I'm having a lot of problems with them, because it looks like browsers (tested in [Google Chrome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome) and [Firefox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mozilla_Firefox)) are aborting requests without giving me an error. I've done a clean page to test what can be causing this issue and the error persists. I've tried a test doing 10 requests inside a `for` loop (I believe we don't have any problem with it, right?).

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Test page</title>
    </head>
    <body>Test page.
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/compressed_jquery-1.8.2.min_1.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    $.get('/i18n/javaScript/pt.json', function(data) {
                        console.log(data);
                    });
                }
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here is a screenshot of requests result in [Firebug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firebug_%28software%29):

[image: Ajax requests screenshot]

As you can see, some requests are completed and others are not. Sometimes the browser completes all 10 requests without errors. What can be causing this?

---

I've tested all the solutions, but I'm pretty sure it's a Windows, Apache or PHP configuration issue. Today I've configured a [VM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_machine) in my machine with [VirtualBox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VirtualBox) running [Ubuntu 13.04](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubuntu_releases#Ubuntu_13.04_.28Raring_Ringtail.29) (Raring Ringtail) with Apache 2.2 + PHP, and NO ERRORS happenned, proving that is nothing with my [JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript), [HTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML) or PHP code. I am not sure it is a configuration issue. How do I discover this configuration?

Comment: Looks like all the requests are to the same URL: so is each request aborted because it has been fulfilled by the cache or because there is an error? Do things change if you add a random querystring value i.e. to bust the cache?

Comment: I don't believe it's a query issue because when cache is used, browser gets a 302 (not changed) response. And in my real code all requests have different URL's.

Comment: I've tried my example with this url: '/i18n/javaScript/pt.json?t=' + Math.floor(Math.random()*101) and the error persists. It's not a cache issue. =/

Comment: In that case have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238135/is-having-too-many-multiple-simultaneous-ajax-connections-bad

Comment: I didn't know about this king of limitation. So I can only do 4 requests at the same time? I don't see how can I do that because in my page I have a lot of requests of different bundles. There is any alternative to that?

Comment: The concurrent connection limit on most modern browsers is now around 6, but ... you should look into the performance benefits of concatenating your javascript (and CSS) assets

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29884/discussion-between-thefrontender-and-hugomn)

Comment: I don't believe it's a concurrent connection limit also. I've done some tests with only two requests and I continue getting errors. Maybe some Apache configuration?

Comment: It's not a browser issue definely. In production environment the same page works without any problem. So it can't be a browser error. I really believe it's something with my local apache (WAMP server 2.2)

Comment: This problem is really a very boring issue. I've researched a lot of issue and nothing solved. In my test environment (which is linux) I don't have any problems, using the same browser (which proves me it's my dev environment issue - Apache with wamp 2.2). Anyone have any ideias on what can be causing this?

Comment: Have a look at http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?590742-WAMP-Only-1-script-per-time-served-How-to-handle-multiple-requests

Comment: My `session.auto_start` in php.ini is already off. =/

Comment: I'm not sure if this is your case or not, but I've had a similar problem here: [Using Eclipse PDT for debugging Ajax pages with concurrent requests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11469297/using-eclipse-pdt-for-debugging-ajax-pages-with-concurrent-requests)

Comment: If you're certain it's not a browser issue (have you written a test client application to test that theory?), then it's more likely to be a server issue, in which case we'd need to know more about what the server is doing.

Comment: The answer is here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12116641/how-to-solve-firebugs-aborted-messages-upon-ajax-requests

Comment: @EricCitaire That answer states *"Better yet, use jQuery or other JS library to do AJAX. It should shield you from these intricacies."* - hugomn is already using jQuery, according to the answer you've linked, he shouldn't be experiencing this issue.

Comment: @Snixtor You're right. I should have read more carefully. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could fit your needs, sending request one by one should avoid server rejecting some parallel requests:

[TEST IT](http://jsfiddle.net/yW9w7/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var tot = 30; //to simulate 30 requests
    (function request(i){
        if(i === tot) return;
        $.get('/echo/html/?'+i, function (data) {
            console.log("success");
        }).always(function() { request(++i) });
    })(0);
});
```

Comment: THank you @roasted, but as I said it doesn't work because it's not the same request that is being made. It is a lot of different request coming from different resources (one doesn't not know about other). I used this logic only as a test. But anyway can't be it because running the code the runs parallel request in my server occrus with success! =/

Comment: The server cannot process more than a set number of requests from a single client at a time. This is to prevent your server from getting hosed by a single client. It does not matter that they are all different requests if they are all to the same host. Per the HTTP spec, the max allowed is 2 at a time. Some servers and browsers give you slightly more than this.

Comment: There is a hack where you can alias out subdomains and point them to the root domain.  Most browsers will then give you two connections per subdomain, plus two for the root domain.

Answer (score 2):

I think your server is taking too long to respond and the browser is timing out. It may be that the browser will only have two open connections to the server and is aborting the last 8/10 when the first two take too long. I would check your server logs to confirm this.

What is the server doing when it sees a request to `/i18n/javaScript/pt.json`? Four seconds is a long time. Try fetching some static content like an image or some static [HTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML) instead of `pt.json` and see if that fixes the problem.

If you need to do a lot of computation to produce `pt.json`, can it be cached? Is it very large? Are you using Apache?

Comment: it's not a complex request. It's a json returned by server that contains only 2kb. But let's assume can be it, because it's my DEV environment and that are a lot of debug messages turned on. How can I make the browser not timing out with these requests? I'm using Apache with Wamp 2.2

Comment: Before trying to fix it, step one is to confirm what I'm saying is true. Did you try ajax loading some static files?

Answer (score 2):

You can serialize requests with a global object:

```
function AjaxRequester() {
    this.queue = [];
}

AjaxRequester.prototype.doRequest(request){
    if (this.queue.length>0){
        this.queue.push(request)
    }
    else 
       handleRequest(request)
}

AjaxRequester.prototype.handleRequest(request){
    /* actually handle ajax request, on complete inspect 
       queue and if not empty recall this method on the first
       element */
}

requester = new AjaxRequester();
```

into your code, do

```
requester.doRequest(yourRequest);
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is a cache issue then you may try this:

Add the following markup in your page's header. That will prevent the browser from caching any data.

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1990 12:00:00 GMT" />
```

This will disable caching in most of the browsers, and your data will be fetched  on each refresh as there is no cache,

One more thing. Your data is called in loop... I can say it is a continuous  call with same request, so the request might be considered as a duplicate request and may get cancelled by the service; As that might be considered as a flood of requests if the same request is sent again and again...

Try adding something while calling, like this..

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    $.get('/i18n/javaScript/pt.json?v='+i, function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
}
```

And handle the request with something. Try and see if it works..

If calling open() using, as you are using, [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery), it's built in, and it will have an effect.

Refer an Stack Overflow Old Post *[How to solve Firebug’s “Aborted” messages upon Ajax requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12116641)*.

I am sure this will give you positive lead towards solution...